# Teradata SQL HHMM to HH:MM

Tags: sql, format, teradata

On Teradata SQL I am trying to convert the duration 30 hours and 30 minutes given as '3030' to 1) 30:30 and 2) 30.5 . Or, in another example 3 hours and 15 minutes as 1) 3:10 and 3) 3.25

I can use mod and other arithmetic operations. However, is there a default way of doing this in Teradata SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert the character:

```
select substr(val, 1, 2) || ':' substr(val, 3, 2)
```

Or, convert the values to integers:

```
select cast(substr(val, 1, 2) as decimal(10, 2)) + cast(substr(val, 3, 2) as decimal(10, 2))/60.0
```

EDIT:

If you want to convert them to a number, you can do:

```
select (cast(hhmm as int) / 100 + (cast(hhmm as int) mod 100) / 60.0
```

This will return a number.

Comment: I think my SQL title was misleading. It may not necessarily be HHMM. It could be '930' for 9 hours and 30 minutes. In this case, I can't substring for the hour. I could do 'char_length' and so forth, but I am wondering if there's some standard format for the interval

Comment: Then you could possibly have something 91 for 9:01?  More examples in your post would help.  But I don't think there's any pretty or clean way to do this, with the unpredictable number of characters.

Comment: May be there isn't a clean way after all. One would think this is quite standard.

Answer (score 0):

Every interval has a FORMAT

```
select format(interval '3:30' hour to minute)
```

returns

```
-h(1):mm
```

but I never found a way to change it :-(

Assuming that you input is a string:

```
cast(col as int) / 100 + to_number(col) mod 100 / 60 -- numeric result

trim(cast(col as int format 'Z(8)9:99'))  -- string result
```

Comment: Hi, the mod thing is exactly what I have been doing, and was trying to find a default way of doing it. Perhaps there really is none.